# Xamarin forms maps error :"Not compatable code running

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a simple map page using Xamarin forms maps checking this project only on Andorid.

I Installed the Xamarin forms map. and added the Xaml Below, 
in addition I've added the in the Android manifest XML all the relavent 
premiisions and Key.

however I am getting this error:Not compatable code running  the selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread

would appericate any help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
         xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
         x:Class="MashamApp.mapPage" Title="מפה" >
<ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage.Content>

<Grid>

    <maps:Map     x:Name="LocationMap"                     
                  IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="True"
                  MapType="Hybrid"
                  HasScrollEnabled="True"
                  HasZoomEnabled="True"                      
                  HeightRequest="480" 
                  WidthRequest="480"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

    </maps:Map>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You have grid outside ContentPage.Content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Yuri, a content page should only have a single view or layout.

Change your page to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
         xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
         x:Class="MashamApp.mapPage" Title="מפה" >
    <Grid>
        <maps:Map     x:Name="LocationMap"                     
                      IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="True"
                      MapType="Hybrid"
                      HasScrollEnabled="True"
                      HasZoomEnabled="True"                      
                      HeightRequest="480" 
                      WidthRequest="480"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

        </maps:Map>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

You don't even need the Grid unless you are going to add more views inside it.

[See here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/) for more details

Comment: not compile reciving this error:
Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: ContentPage. Line 18, position 12.

Comment: Sorry - I missed off the </ContentPage>. Fixed now.